# What is bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, meta, subdomains

I accidentally found this page: http://bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com/

It looks just like the normal Meta. Upon the second look, though, I noticed that all questions there have the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag, on the main page and in search results. Is it just Meta filtered by tag? What happens if I post there? *(I posted this via `bugs.meta`. It seemed to work fine. The question didn't appear on the main page, as it isn't tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug))*

I haven't found a similar "shortcut" for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Who and what is that page for? How can I use it?

Comment: You posted this via bugs.meta? .... you might want to lock your doors...

Comment: @Bart How much trouble are we looking at? Will it be humans?

Comment: Ha...humans....

Comment: I guess this is why we often see devs who comment on posts to say don't misuse the [bug] tag. They must have been keeping an eye on that page to see new bugs in the system.

Comment: I guess this was the test for [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @hammar Oh, I should have looked closer at the FAQ. It answers my question for the most part.

Comment: I didn't even know this existed. Now I wonder what else they don't tell me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's Meta filtered by the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag. It appears to be using the same functionality that was implemented for the [Facebook Stack Overflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) mini-site, so I expect everything to work exactly the same as how it does there.

If you look at the [FAQ page](http://bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), it has the same ["What questions appear here?" section](http://bugs.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#tagsshown) as [Facebook.so](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#tagsshown):

> ### What questions appear here?
>
> Questions asked on Meta Stack Overflow with bugs related tags. If you
>   want your question to appear here, it must have one of those tags.
>
> These tags are considered bugs related.
>
> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it just Meta filtered by tag?

Yes.

> I haven't found a similar "shortcut" for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Because the devs haven't found a need to implement this feature request for any arbitrary tag, or even those two other tags.  They just did it for bugs, [presumably] both because they spend a lot of time looking through bug tags, and when people suspect a new bug they ought to be looking through recent bug reports for dups.  It's easier to yell at people for posing duplicate bug reports when there are easy ways of finding them.  With discussion/support tags you're generally using the search, not just the list of all items in that tag.

Comment: Any sources for your "opinion"? Experience?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Pretty much.  In the end it doesn't much matter.  They felt that it was wroth the time/effort for bugs but not for others.  If you would really like to see a subsite for the others then make a feature request.  Personally I don't see a compelling need.